# What language is Space Engineers programmed in?

Tags: space-engineers

I've tried searching online for this - but I always end up in the in-game programming language (C#) sites, but I'm curious what the game itself is programmed in. I would assume a game like this would be C++, but you never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code of the game](https://github.com/KeenSoftwareHouse/SpaceEngineers) (albeit an outdated version as stated in the [README](https://github.com/KeenSoftwareHouse/SpaceEngineers/blob/master/README.md)), is available on GitHub from [KeenSoftwareHouse](https://github.com/KeenSoftwareHouse) - the game developers themselves.

It appears to be primarily written in C# with a few shader files.

Comment: Wow thanks -- it never occurred to me that the source (even an older version) would be open sourced. So refreshing to see that.. Thanks!