# What programming language or game engine is Hogwarts Legacies written in?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I was curious as to what was used to make this game.

What programming language or game engine was used to create Hogwarts Legacies?

Comment: Why the downvotes? What's different between my question and this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396336/what-language-is-space-engineers-programmed-in

Comment: Did the question need to be asked?  It's not like Wikipedia already tells you what engine the game runs on. Taking information that is already widely available online and then reposting it here as a question/self-answer format doesn't help anybody

Comment: @ShaunRoselt This question (and many of your others) are getting downvotes because you're just spamming stuff that's readily available elsewhere. It's one thing to have a really detailed self-answer, or something that isn't easily found, but as it is you're just filling up the front page. Questions like this are fine if they're organic, but tend to annoy people when done in this way.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Not everything is readily available. A lot of these questions are things I'm wondering about or needing. So I ask the question and then do research and try to find the answer to the question. If I'm able to answer it myself, then I answer it. If I'm not able to find an answer to my own question, then I don't answer it such as this one: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403695/can-you-tell-ominis-about-sebastian-using-dark-magic-again-in-hogwarts-legacy

Comment: also worth noticing that while @ChrisHayes already has a point, the question is also off-topic in the first place.

Comment: @Ꮢedacted If this question doesn't belong here. Then where does it belong? Nowhere? It definitely doesn't belong in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ either as can be seen here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (It seems like it belongs more here than there, but the closed message says that it belongs there and then links the FAQ that clearly states it doesn't)

Comment: The FAQ links the other site because game dev questions **may** be suitable for that site. This kind of question is useless for Arqade, we don't matter the programming languages nor game engines because they have nothing to do with the game itself. Just because you have a curiosity it doesn't mean there must be a SE site for it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Unreal Engine 4**, according to the [Hogwarts Legacy Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogwarts_Legacy), [PrimaGames.com](https://primagames.com/tips/what-engine-does-hogwarts-legacy-run-on-answered), [Videogamer.com](https://www.videogamer.com/news/is-hogwarts-legacy-on-unreal-engine-5/), and many other online sources. This was also confirmed by the developers of the game.

So, what coding language does Unreal Engine 4 use? Unreal Engine 4 uses **C++**, with a few modules written in **Blueprint scripting**. That said, you don’t need to be a C++ expert to develop games using UE4. The engine has been designed so that you can create games without having to write any code at all! However, if you want to get the most out of the engine and really customize your game, then C++ will give you the power to do that. So the developers of Hogwarts Legacy most definitely used C++ as well to customize the game.